# Makefile rule for `mount` run as root throws `make: mount: Permission denied` error

Tags: makefile, permissions, gnu-make, mount

I've scratching my head for while with this one. Here is a Makefile which reproduce this behavior:

```
IMAGE := sda.img
MOUNTPOINT := ./mnt

mount_image:
        mount -o loop $(IMAGE) $(MOUNTPOINT)

.PHONY: mount_image
```

Now, if i run `make` from a root shell **or** run `sudo make`, i get this error message:

```
mount -o loop sda.img ./mnt
make: mount: Permission denied
make: *** [Makefile:5: mount_image] Error 127
```

But if i run `doas make` as user, it just works fine. Same for mounting it manually as root. Why? :-)

Duno if this is important but here is my `doas.conf`

```
permit persist :wheel
```

Probably it is, and my guess is it had something to do with sub shells?

Answer (score 0):

Found it! Turned out i had in my `~/script` directoy an folder named `mount` which holds some shell scripts.. `~/script` is in `$PATH`. Somehow `make` and `sudo` find that `~/script/mount` directory and tried to execute it. Very strange because it's just a ordinary folder. And `doas` didn't show that behavior. Any how `strace` was my friend.